# Webpack alias with Angular - Cannot use namespace 'UtilsService' as a type

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, alias, resolve

I have a project with Angular 6, Typescript, webpack 4.

I want to use [alias in webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) in order to make my import statement clearer.

This is the code I have in webpack:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    assets: `${helpers.root('src/assets/')}`,
    app: `${helpers.root('src/app/')}`
  },
}
```

**The "assets" alias is working fine !**

I use the "app" alias in this way within the code of a component:

```
import { UtilsService } from 'app/_services/utils.service';
```

And this is the constructor of the component:

```
constructor( @Inject( UtilsService ) private utils: UtilsService, ) {
}
```

I don't have an error on the import statement, so I guess that the alias works in some way.

But I have the following error in the constructor:

**TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'UtilsService' as a type.**

I must be missing some configuration somewhere but can't figure out what ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

---

**EDIT:**
**Following kemsky and David comment this is what I tried:**

I added the following in tsconfig.json:

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@app": ["src/app/"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
}
```

I modify webpack.config.js to have:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    assets: `${helpers.root('src/assets/')}`,
    '@app': `${helpers.root('src/app/')}`
  },
}
```

And I tried to import using:

```
import { UtilsService } from 'app/_services/utils.service';
```

I still have the same error in the constructor of my component:

```
constructor( private utils: UtilsService, ) {}
```

**TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'UtilsService' as a type.**

If I change the import statement to something that don't exist, I have a the following error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@DONT_EXIST/_services/utils.service'
```

Which makes me think that the problem is with tsconfig.

Note:

I'm using awesome-typescript-loader, maybe it's linked, this is how I load tsconfig.json inside webpack.config.js

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.ts$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'tslint-loader'
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
          options: {
            pretty: !isProd,
            prod: isProd
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'ng-router-loader',
          options: {
            loader: 'async-import',
            genDir: 'compiled',
            aot: AOT
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          options: {
            configFileName: 'tsconfig.json',
            useCache: !isProd
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'angular2-template-loader'
        }
      ],
      exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
    },
```

Comment: See example here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18484 probably you should also change tsconfig.

Comment: Why do you need to specify `@Inject( UtilsService )`? How did you provide the service?

Comment: @David I don't really need to provide it, it works exactly the same if I don't write @Inject( UtilsService ). The question is more about the alias in webpack

Comment: Oh ok I thought it was the inject causing the issue. So in your `utils.service` file you do export the `UtilsService` class correctly? If so, as suggested by @kemsky you could change tsconfig.json (insted of webpack) to declare the '@app' alias and try using the aliased import `import {UtilsService} from '@app/_services/utils.service;`

Comment: @David: See my edits, I tried but no luck. :-(

Comment: Does it make a difference with `"@app/*": [
        "src/app/*"
      ]`

Comment: Damn amazing, that made the difference !! No more error and I can use alias instead of having a bunch of ../../../.. for my import path. answer the question and I'll accept it. Amazing, thanks, I've been trying for ages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When defining path mappings, it's necessary to add '*' so that it works for all subpaths (as you are actually defining a pattern)

So your tsconfig.json should contain

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "@app/*": ["src/app/*"] // This mapping is relative to "baseUrl"
}
```

That way, all modules matching `@app/*` such as

```
import {x}  from '@app/<moduleName>;
```

will resolve to

```
<baseUrl>/src/app/<moduleName>
```

More about module resolution [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)